# Create multiple div structure dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery for create a structure dynamically,

I'm trying to solve a problem with a div..

But, I don't know why? my div "content" is closed directly...

my result:

```
<li class="monde">
    <div class="content">
    </div>        // -----------> problem content div here 
    <div class="ctn_img">
        <img src="myimage.png" />
    </div>
        <div class="choix">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
        </div>
    <div class="infos">
        <span class="caption">
            <a href="#"><span class="stats">Etats</span></a>
            <input type="text" class="name" />
            <span class="test">test</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    // <-------------- better content close here...
    <span class="glob">Global</span>
</li>
```

My [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/baAUt/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var content    = $('<div>').addClass('content'),
    image      = $("<img>").attr('src', 'myimage.png'),
    ctn_img    = $('<div>').addClass('ctn_img').append(image),
    choix      = $('<div>').addClass('choix').html('<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />'),
    caption    = $('<span>').addClass('caption').html('<a href="#"><span class="stats">Etats</span></a><input type="text" class="name"></span><span class="test">test</span>'),
    infos      = $('<div>').addClass('infos').append(caption),
    glob       = $('<span>').addClass('glob').html('Global');

    content.append(ctn_img).append(choix).append(infos).append(glob);
    var result = $('<li>').addClass('monde').append(content);

$(document.body).html(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you should append elements with classes `.ctn_img`, `.choix` and `.infos` to `.content`, and not to `<li>`, i.e.

```
// ...
ctn_img = $('<div>').addClass('ctn_img').append(image).appendTo(content),
choix   = $('<div>').addClass('choix').html('<input ... />').appendTo(content),
infos   = $('<div>').addClass('infos').append(caption).appendTo(content),
// ...
result = $('<li>').addClass('monde').append(content, glob);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nGRwJ/1/

Comment: Thank you, i know where was my problem now :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach have at least two disadvantages:

1. Really hard to maintain a structure (you faced this problem).
2. Too many `append` and DOM manipulations decrease performance.

What about building HTML like this:

```
var result = $([
    '<li class="monde">',
        '<div class="content">',
            '<div class="ctn_img">',
                '<img src="myimage.png">',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="choix">',
                '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="infos">',
                '<span class="caption">',
                    '<a href="#"><span class="stats">Etats</span></a>',
                    '<input type="text" class="name">',
                    '<span class="test">test</span>',
                '</span>',
            '</div>',
        '</div>',
        '<span class="glob">Global</span>',
    '</li>'
].join(''));

$(document.body).html(result);
```

Much easier to read. Or consider using templates.

http://jsfiddle.net/baAUt/1/

Comment: This approach is good but has one big disadvantage. *It is slow.* Using `innerHTML` property (or `html()` method of jQuery) for modifying elements' structure makes DOM to serialize/deserialize the markup, while creating and appending elements is many times faster, since works with tree directly.

Comment: Thank you for answer,I know you'r approach, it's easy for maintaining a template, but I prefer a complicated structure for learning....